# In which way GAN generator transforms the data(for transforming a noise to the data)?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gan, generative-models

I have the problem: I understood how GAN works in general, but I need information how it work detailed. The part I don't understand is how the random noise at input is transformed to data on the output(the math side of that process). If anybody knows answer for the question please say it or at least say in which side I need google the question.